# AG-GRID Angular : Is there a difference between cellEditor and cellrenderer which calls params.setValue()

Tags: javascript, angular, user-interface, ag-grid

Is one better than the other/ do things differently? which one is preferred?

Edit - I'm creating a cellRenderer component with 3 different screens depending on data and user action (Refer image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuSEB.png). I'm using ngSwitch to switch between different screens in the template, and saving it using this.params.setValue(name). here's the component class file -

```js
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'description-cell',
  templateUrl: './description-cell.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./description-cell.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class DescriptionCellComponent {
  params;
  description: string;
  mode; // set, unset, in-cell-editor

  constructor() { }
  
  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
    this.description = params?.value || null;
    this.mode = this.description? 'set' : 'unset';
  }

  pickDescription() {
    //open modal
    this.params.context.componentParent.onPickDescriptionButtonClicked({ type: 'pickDescription', params: this.params });
  }

  inputDescription() {
    this.mode = 'in-cell-editor';
  }

  removeDescription() {
    this.description = null;
    this.params.setValue(null);
    this.mode = 'unset';
  }

  saveDescription(){
    this.params.setValue(this.description); //and then reload ag-grid to reflect changes?
    this.mode = 'set';
  }

  cancelEditing() {
    this.mode = 'unset';
  }
}
```

and here is the template -

```html
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="mode">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'set'">
        <span>{{ description }}</span>
        <br>
        <a (click)="removeDescription()">Remove description</a>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'unset'">
        <a (click)="pickDescription()">Pick description from PO</a>
        <br>
        <a (click)="inputDescription()">Input description</a>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'in-cell-editor'">
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="description">
        <a (click)="saveDescription()">Save</a>
        <br>
        <a (click)="cancelEditing()">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

is this approach correct? or should I use the cellEditor functionality provided by ag-grid?

another followup question, if I want to enable editing for the whole row on hover, which approach will be easier/intuitive?

Comment: Your question is very ambiguous. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Add more details in question like what are three different screens, why you want to use cell renderer, what code you have written till now etc.

Comment: @DRASHTIDOBARIYA Hi sorry for the loose question. I've added more details. let me know if there's more info i can proide. i'm new to ag-grid.

Comment: Please add html file for this component.

Comment: @DRASHTIDOBARIYA added

Answer (score 0):

By default, ag-grid uses simple text values in cells. If you want more complex HTML, like buttons, checkboxes, etc, then you can use cell renderer.
This will be used to display the cell values based on the renderer component.

Cell Editors will only be initiated by aggrid, when an edit event is triggered on cell. It can be via click on cell, enter press etc. After an edit is made, grid again calls cell renderer to display the new value.

From my interpretation of your code, you want to change the description field.

If you use cell renderer then buttons and input elements will always be present in the grid, even when there is no edit event on the grid.

If you use cell editor, then when an edit event is triggered then this HTML will be displayed. On completion of the edition, it will be removed from the grid and edited value will be displayed.

Cell Editor and Cell Renderer both are custom ag-grid elements. Using either would affect the performance of ag-grid. However, Cell Renderer will be called for each rows every time there is some change in life cycle change whereas cell editor will be renderer only during edit event on cell. Thus the performance of cell Editors is better than that of cell renderers.

Editing entire row on hover will lead to ag-grid performance issues. I suggest you use aggrid's standard [full row editing](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/cell-editing/#full-row-edit-and-popup-editors).
This will only work with cell editors. If you have not provided custom cell editors for some field, then ag-grid will enable in-built text editors for that field. It is shown in the example below.

[Example of fullRow Edit - Plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/1NZVLBgVLlRMrJaaRtOb/)

Another suggestion to edit the entire row would be to open a modal with the click of the ag-grid cell. This can also be done in various ways

- you can click on any cell to start editing
- you can create a custom renderer with edit icon and click of that icon, you can open the modal.

In this modal, you can create a form to edit the row values and save changes on press of button( you can customize the form however you want. For example you can have cacel button to discard changes and close modal)